# Cant seem to figure out this Big O notation from my text book

Tags: math, big-o

```
for(int i=n; i>0; i--) { 
 for(int j=n; j>i; j--) {
 System.out.println("Algorithm analysis"); }
}
```

is the original code given.

the author states the time complexity to be c* (n-1)*n/2.I agree with this. But then he goes to say that it reduces to O(n) which i am stumped on, i'd have thought it'd be O(n^2).

Comment: I think you probably want `>` instead of `<`?

Comment: I think I agree with you though - according to wikipedia (that great source of authoritative information), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, you can write your function as `n^2/2 - n/2 --> 1/2 ( n^2 + |n|) --> 1/2 ( n^2 + n^2) --> n^2`

Comment: In that second to last step, it's assumed that for any value of n (so n must be positive), `n^2 >= n`

Comment: Not quite. Look at `j>i` and think about the logic in the loop. While I can't see it being O(n) I definitely don't believe it to be O(n^2).

Comment: If you write `|n/2(n-1)| <= M|n|`, you end up with `n <= 2M + 1`, which gives no finite M for increasing n. On the other hand, taking `<= M|n^2|`, you get `1/n >= 1-2M`, which is true for all n>0, M taking any positive value above 1/2, so for example, 1*(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see it - you need at least O(n^2). You can write O(n^100), if you want, but I assume you don't.

Start by writing `|(n/2)(n-1)| <= M|g(n)|`
So long as you don't have `0 <= n <= 1`, which is excluded by your `int i=n` etc, the left hand side is always positive. Therefore,

`(n/2)(n-1) <= M|g(n)|`

Now, we can write `g(n) = n^(x+1)`, since we can't find an M for `O(n)`, and we're looking to get smaller than `O(n^2)`. As such, we're looking for `0 <= x <= 1`, as `x=0` is the `O(n)` case and `x=1` is the `O(n^2)` case.

Dividing through by `n/2`, we're left with:

`n-1 <= 2M (n^x)`, or `n <= 2M(n^x)+1`.

Dividing again, and taking logarithms (`log(1) = 0`, and we can divide safely by n since we're set on `n>1`)

`1 <= 2M(n^(x-1)) + (1/n)`, --> `0 <= log(2M) + (x-1)*log(n) - n`

For our statement to now be true, we require that

`log(2M)/n + (x-1)*(log(n)/n) >= 0`.

`(1/n)*(log(2M) + (x-1)*log(n)) >= 0` is our statement now.

(1/n) is positive for n > 1.

log(2M) is positive for 2M > 1.

log(n) is positive, since n > 1.

(x-1) is negative for any value of x smaller than 1, so either x>=1, making our equation `O(n^2)`, or

`log(2M) >= (1-x) * log(n)`.

For order (n), x=0, leaving `log(2M) >= log(n)`. Whilst this expands slowly, it is infinite, so no value of M can be found.

Seems like you won't be getting an order(n) equation out. Please point out where I've gone wrong if this isn't the case

Comment: Strictly, I suppose you need `log(2M) > (1-x) * log(n)`, regardless of the value of x. It's just satisfied for M>0.5 in the case of x=1.